# Python: Loop through directory, check if certain amount of files is in there, if not; copy 2 files from other directory and one file based on name

Tags: python

I'm still in the learning proces of python.

I'm trying to make a script that does the following:

- Loop through directory's based on todays date (so if I run it tomorrow, itll look for the folders with tomorrows date on it).
- Check if there are .pdf files in it.
- If there arent any .pdf files in them: copy standard 2 of them from another directory + copy one based on name of the excel file name. (So lets say the excel filed is called: Excelfile45 then it should copy the pdf file called: "45") *EDIT: It can also be based on directory map if that is an easier way of doing things.*

So this is I got this far:

```
import os, fnmatch
```

def findDir (path, filter):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
        yield os.path.join(root, file)
```

for pdfFile in findDir(r'C:\new', '*.pdf'):
    print(pdfFile)

Its runs through the directories and looks for PDF's in them. But now I've got no clue on how to continue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also my apologies for any grammar / spelling errors.

Comment: Sadly, we tend not to help with writing 'teh codez' for you. If you have a specific problem, we can help with that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specs are pretty vague, so I had to assume a lot of things. I think this code achieves what you want, but you may have to tweak it a bit (for example date format in the directory name).

I assumed a directory structure like this:

```
c:\new (base dir)
    daily_2014_12_14
    daily_2014_12_15
    ...
    standard
```

And the code:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import time
import shutil
import re

# directories    
base_dir = "C:\new"
standard_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, "standard")

# find files in directory. based on yours, but modified to return a list.
def find_dir(path, name_filter):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, name_filter):
            result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return result

# getting today's directory. you can rearrange year-month-day as you want.
def todays_dir():
    date_str = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
    return os.path.join(base_dir, "daily_" + date_str)

# copy a file from one directory to another
def copy(filename, from_dir, to_dir):
    from_file = os.path.join(from_dir, filename)
    to_file = os.path.join(to_dir, filename)
    shutil.copyfile(from_file, to_file)

# main logic
today_dir = todays_dir()
pdfs = find_dir(today_dir, "*.pdf")
excels = find_dir(today_dir, "*.xls")
if len(pdfs) == 0:
    copy("standard1.pdf", standard_dir, today_dir)
    copy("standard2.pdf", standard_dir, today_dir)
    if len(excels) == 1:
        excel_name = os.path.splitext(excels[0])[0]
        excel_num = re.findall(r"\d+", excel_name)[-1]
        copy(excel_num + ".pdf", standard_dir, today_dir)
```

Also: I agree with Iplodman's comment. Show us a bit more effort next time.

Comment: I would really like to thank you a lot ! this helped me alot. The problem i have with Python is is that I nearly finished my first book, so my exp. with it is like 0.0%. A great thanks for me helping me out this much !

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer, if it helped to solve your problem.